# Recenter several stacked rasters in the Pacific ocean

Tags: r, mapping, r-raster

I am currently working in R with environmental data at a regional scale in Australasia for modeling species distribution. I converted these environmental files into raster for the analyzes, using the `raster` package and stack them together.
All of these raster are centered around the Greenwich meridian. However, for visualization purpose, I would like to be able to plot these raster centering them on the Pacific Ocean.

I tried to modify the CRS, but it didn´t change the plot output.

Can anyone suggest a way to recenter the raster in the meridian 180?

Thank you very much

This code is a simpler version of the code I have used.

```
xy <- matrix(rnorm(400),20,20)
rast <- raster(xy)
extent(rast) <- c(-180, 180, -60, -3.197442e-14)
projection(rast) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
plot(rast)
```

Comment: What does it mean 'wasn't successful'? What do you get instead of expected result?

Comment: Please provide a usable example. Yours refers to files we do not have, and is unnecessarily long. You should create a small example data set in memory using `raster(.... )` and take it from there.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, When I used flip and rotate I was hoping they will let me turn around the map to center the map in the pacific ocean, but they had different functions.